# CakePHP 3.6: protect inner page with existin login form

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, oauth, authorization

I have used [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=747K6W40ur0) to create a login screen for my application. But I want to protect with the same login form another inner page. So a user can login and use the application but if he/she wishes to open a specific page in the application he/she has to reenter the password for security reasons. How I can achieve that?

This is my initialize function in `AppController.php`:

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
                'authenticate' => [
                    'Form' => [
                        'fields' => [
                            'username' => 'email',
                            'password' => 'password'
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                'loginAction' => [
                    'controller' => 'Users',
                    'action' => 'login'
                ]
            ]);
```

Comment: I don't think the built in parts can handle this. You might have to write your own logic for the specific password input.
I would recommend looking into [Passwordable behavior](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tools/blob/master/docs/Behavior/Passwordable.md) as it provides a way to re-confirm existing passwords in forms. Would not be too difficult to implement for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the `AuthComponent::identify()` method to check a login form even in a already authenticated enviroment. See [Identifying Users and Logging Them In](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#identifying-users-and-logging-them-in) in the CakePHP docs and [AuthComponent::identify](https://api.cakephp.org/3.6/class-Cake.Controller.Component.AuthComponent.html#_identify) in the API docs.

Step-by-step:

1. Create controller action and template for password recheck and include form for a `User` entity with controls for `email` and `password`.
2. Prefill `email` field if you like, a hidden field is also possible.
3. Add a `$this->request->is('post')` block, just the way you would do in the standard login and check for valid crendential within using `$user = $this->Auth->identify();`.
4. If a valid user is returned store some flag or timestamp for timeout in your [Session](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html) and then redirect to protected pages.
5. On any protected controller check for existence of the flag or valid timestamp in the [Controller::beforeFilter](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#Cake%5CController%5CController::beforeFilter) callback method and throw `UnauthorizedException` or `ForbiddenException` if not.